# I'm trying to create a table with a foreign key but i keep getting the ORA-00904 error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-key-relationship, ddl

```
create table reservation (
    reserve_id number PRIMARY KEY,
    date_in       TIMESTAMP,
    date_out    TIMESTAMP,
    made_by    number(4),
    constraint LocationID_fk foreign key (locId) references location(locId),
    constraint fk_guest_id foreign key (guest_id) references guest(guest_id)
);
```

--these are the parent tables

```
create table guest(
   guest_id NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   fname varchar(10),
   lname varchar(5),
   email varchar(10)
);

Create table location (
   locId  NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
   loc_name  varchar(10),
   manager_name     varchar(15) 
);
```

-------error that keeps coming up

Error report -

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "LOCID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: please elaborate your case

Comment: You usie a key(locId) but you don't have this column in reservation table ..

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand what the constraint definitions do:

```
constraint LocationID_fk foreign key (locId) references location(locId),
constraint fk_guest_id foreign key (guest_id) references guest(guest_id)
```

Maybe you are under the impression that by defining the foreign key constraints on `locId` and `guest_id`, that it also automatically defines the 2 columns on the `reservation` table?  That is not the case.  You have to explicitly define the 2 columns besides the foreign key constraint definition. Something like:

```
create table reservation (
    reserve_id number PRIMARY KEY,
    date_in       TIMESTAMP,
    date_out      TIMESTAMP,
    made_by       number(4),
    locId         number(4), -- explicitly defined
    guest_id      number(3)  -- explicitly defined
    constraint LocationID_fk foreign key (locId) references location(locId),
    constraint fk_guest_id foreign key (guest_id) references guest(guest_id)
);
```